# Dynamic matrix in class

Tags: c++

I have problem with dynamic allocation in c++.
This is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Wektor {

int rozmiar;
float *TabWe;

friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream &Strm, Wektor &Wek);
public:

Wektor(int rozmiar) : rozmiar(rozmiar) {
    TabWe = new float[rozmiar];
}
Wektor() {
    for (int i = 0; i < rozmiar; i++)
    {
        TabWe[i] = 0;
    }
}
~Wektor()
{
    for (int i = 0; i <rozmiar; i++)
    {
        delete[] TabWe;
    }

}
};
istream& operator >>(istream &Strm, Wektor &Wek)
{
cout << "Size: ";
Strm >> Wek.rozmiar;
for (int i = 0; i < Wek.rozmiar; i++)
{
    Strm >> Wek.TabWe[i];
}
return Strm;
}
int main()
{
Wektor wek;
cin >> wek;
}
```

After I enter first value to the matrix I get this error:

[image]

I think there is problem with default constructor, because you can see on the screenshot that this matrix has no value when program starts. What is wrong with it?

Comment: You do realize you never use the `Wektor(int rozmiar)` constructor in your code? So `TabWe` is never initialized by anything. Your problem in this code is that you *aren't* ever doing the dynamic allocation.

Comment: Now i realize that. I modified overload of the >> operator, and it works. Thanks